# Interested in optimizing the number of appointments based on the counts of two features

Tags: regression, optimization, boosting

Key Facts:

- Currently have a regression model (XGBoost) that takes 85 features and predicts the number of appointments.
- There are two features that I am particularly interested in optimizing 2 features. Lets call them, `Value A` and `Value B`

Problem:

- To provide a recommended strategy, I'd like to optimize `Value A` and `Value B` to maximize the number of appointments.

Questions:

- How would I do this since i'm just trying to optimize 2 of 85 features?
- Should I just simulate increasing/decreasing these two features within my test set? I'd them predict the number of appointments for each variation and use the global maximum.

I know very little about optimization so any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I would begin analysis with visual inspection of a 3D scatterplot of A, B, and appointments. That would inform you as to whether the data lies on (best case) a surface to be modeled or (worst case) a random-looking point cloud.